# Is there a way to get the values out of a success handler without calling another function?

Tags: asynchronous, google-apps-script, web-applications

Ok so right now I'm doing this:

```
google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(updateOutput)
  .withFailureHandler(errorOutput)
  .finish();
```

And then

```
  function updateOutput(info) 
  {
    var br='<br />';
    var outputDiv = document.getElementById('status');
    outputDiv.innerHTML = 'First Logic Compete' + br +   br +'GotoLogic: ' +info.slide+ br + 'Copy text: ' + info.text + br ;  
  }
```

Is there any way to cut out the need to call another function? and directly interact with the `google.script.run` result object inside the first function?

Edit, this doesn't work either, the number returned is blank:

```
var object = google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(function (number) {
    document.getElementById('bugLink').href = "https://bug.com/issues/" + number;
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = number;
  })
  .finish();
```

Answer (score 4):

A handler to be called by the other code whenever the other code is done is a requirement of asynchronous communication. If you want, you can define the handler inline:

```
const TASK = google.script.run.withFailureHandler(errorOutput);
TASK
  .withSuccessHandler((info, userObj) => {
    ...
  })
  .foo();
TASK
  .withSuccessHandler((otherInfo, userObj) => {
    ...
  })
  .otherFoo();
...
```

Or if you despise callbacks, you can use Promises in your client side HTML:

```
const makeAppsScriptCall = (fnName, obj, ...args) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let TASK = google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(resolve)
      .withFailureHandler(reject);
    if (obj) {
      TASK = TASK.withUserObject(obj);
    }
    if (TASK[fnName] === undefined) {
      reject("'" + fnName + "' is not a global function in your Apps Script project");
    } else {
      TASK[fnName].apply(null, args);
    }
  });
};

function doStuffAsPromises(userObjBtn) {
  makeAppsScriptCall("finish", userObjBtn, myarg1, myarg2, myarg3, ...)
    .then(...)
    .catch(...);
}
```

(Obviously if the client browser doesn't support Promises or the spread syntax for "rest parameters", you will need to polyfill / modify as appropriate.)

References

- [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)
- [`Promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
- [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)
- [Apps Script client-server communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#success_handlers)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean this?

This is client side:

```
google.script.run
.withSuccessHandler(function(html){
     document.getElementById('id').innerHTML=html;
   })
.getHtml();
```

Server Side:

```
function getHtml() {
  return '<h1>Hello World</h1>';
}
```

Comment: Maybe? I want access to the object passed back from "finish" without having to pass that object to a success function. It kind of looks like you are writing a success function into the handler?

Comment: That will do it.  The object passed back by `getHtml()` in this case is `html`; It's okay to use and anonymous function in this situation.

Comment: Strangely this isn't working: the number returned is blank (SEE ABOVE EDITS)

Comment: You have to write the getHtml() functon in google script.