# Easiest way to wait for google server-side function to resolve

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications, promise, async-await

I need the client side code to wait for the called server side (google.script.run) function to complete before running any more code.

The `withSuccessHandler(successFunc)` does not cause lines of code that are after the server call to wait.

What I've done:

```
async function func(){
   await google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(myFunc).serverFunc();
   console.log("done");
}
func();
```

How can the code wait to execute the `console.log` line until after the server side function resolves?

Comment: does your `serverFunc()` return a promise? Your code should wait for it to resolve as is

Comment: You'll need to wrap your "procedure" (ie the code inside `serverFunc()` in a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), and `resolve()` when the "procedure" is complete. Make your `serverFunc` return this promise so that it can then be awaited.

Comment: @Nick Parsons At `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(myFunc).serverFunc()`, at first, `serverFunc()` is run. This is Google Apps Script and this is run the server of Google side. Unfortunately, this doesn't return promise. As the next step, when no error occurs at `serverFunc()`, `withSuccessHandler` is run and the function of `myFunc` is run. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get the values out of a success handler without calling another function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55247839/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-values-out-of-a-success-handler-without-calling-anothe)

Comment: https://ramblings.mcpher.com/gassnippets2/organizing-asynchronous-calls-to-google-script-run/#Organizing_with_promises

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, after `serverFunc` was run, `myFunc` is run. At that time, `console.log("done")` is run in `myFunc`.

```
function myFunc() {
   console.log("done");
}

function func(){
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(myFunc).serverFunc();
}

func();
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, Promise was used. When you run `func()`, you can see `ok` and `done` in order.

```
function myFunc() {
  return "ok";
}

async function func() {
  await new Promise(r => {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(r).serverFunc();
  });
  const res = myFunc();
  console.log(res);
  console.log("done");
}

func();
```

#### Note:

- If you test above samples, please set the function of `serverFunc()` at Google Apps Script side.
- This is a simple sample script. So please modify this for your actual situation.

#### References:

- [Class google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)
- [withSuccessHandler(function)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function))
- [Using Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

### Added:

If you want to use the values from `serverFunc` at `myFunc`, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunc(nice) {
  doStuffs(nice);

  return "ok";
}

async function func() {
  const e = await new Promise(r => {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(r).serverFunc();
  });
  const res = myFunc(e);
  console.log(res);
  console.log("done");
}

func();
```

- In this script, the returned value from `myFunc` can be retrieved by `res`.

Comment: in my case, myFunc has a parameter which is the return value of serverFunc()

like this:

function serverFunc(){
   doSomething();
   return "nice";
}

function myFunc(nice){
   doStuffs(nice);
}

and i called it like this before:

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(myFunc).serverFunc();

in this case, myFunc is a callback function, and if i apply your solution, there's an error on it because 

... () => r(myFunc())) .... (no parameter on it)

thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Makoto Daiwa Ambara Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, I could know that you try to use the pattern 2. For this, I added one more sample script for your replying. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: it works with no error, but if i apply this:

`console.log(res);
     otherFunc();
     console.log(done);`

the otherFunc() doesn't work with no error, except I use setTimeOut which is makes the whole promise setup being useless.
this is the code inside otherFunc(), probably could extract some ideas why this happen.

Comment: `var btns = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
      var mdls = document.getElementsByClassName("modal_detail");
      var cds = document.getElementsByClassName("close_detail");
      for(var i = 0;i<btns.length-1;i++){
         btns[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
             document.getElementById("mdl"+this.id.slice(3)).style.display = "block";
         });
         mdls[i].style.display = "none";
      }`

Comment: `for(var i=0;i<cds.length;i++){
         cds[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
            for(var j = 0;j<mdls.length;j++){
            console.log(this.id.slice(3) , mdls[j].id);
            if (this.id.slice(3) == mdls[j].id.slice(3)) {
               mdls[j].style.display = "none";
               return;
            }   
         }
         });
      }
      window.onclick = function(event) {
         for(var i = 0;i<mdls.length;i++)
            if (event.target == mdls[i]) {
               mdls[i].style.display = "none";
            }            
      }`

Comment: i found the problem, it doesn't work because btns, mdls, and cds are null because myFunc hasn't complete yet

Comment: please visit my [new issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58423846/simple-promise-callback-google-script-function)

Comment: @Makoto Daiwa Ambara Thank you for your response. I would like to confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

This code includes error handling and two `Promise.then()` methods.
The example given below is the complete code for an Apps Script Web App, that I used for testing purposes to make sure the that code works.
I needed a way to duplicate some client side code that uses `fetch().then()`, replacing the `fetch(url)` call to using Apps Script `google.script.run.fncName()`.

### H_Index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="some_Object_Name.innerNameOne()">Run</button>
    
    <div id="idRslt1">Result One</div>
    <div id="idRslt2">Result 2</div>
    <div id="idError">For error</div>
    
    <script>


function callServerAndGetRslt(po) {
  
  /*
    po.fncName - The name of the fnk to run
  
  */
  
  //console.log('po.fncName ' + po.fncName)
  
  return new Promise (function (resolve,reject) {
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler (function (result) {
        console.log('result 24' + result)
        resolve (result);//What resolve does is return the result from the server back to the FIRST anonymous function in the "then" part
      })
      .withFailureHandler (function (error) {
        console.log('error: ' + error)
        reject (error);
      })[po.fncName](po);//There can NOT be anything inbetween the array and the ending parenthesis 
    })
}

function showError(err) {
  document.getElementById('idError').textContent = err;
  
}

function showResult(toShow) {
  document.getElementById('idRslt1').textContent = toShow;
  
}
function showResult2(toShow) {
  document.getElementById('idRslt2').textContent = toShow;
  
}

window.some_Object_Name = {

  innerNameOne : function() {
    return callServerAndGetRslt ({"fncName":'theFirstServerFncCall'})
      .then (function (result) {
        console.log('result: 45' + result)
        showResult (result);
      
        return callServerAndGetRslt ({"fncName":'serverFncCall2'});
      },//THERE MUST BE A COMMA HERE!!!!  This is a list of functions seperated by a comma
      function (error) {//Because this is the second function this is what gets called for an error
        showError(error);
        return "There was an error in call 1";
      }
      ).then (function (result) {
        showResult2("end result:" + result);
      });
  }
}

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### GS_Test

```
function theFirstServerFncCall(po) {
  Logger.log('po 1: ' + JSON.stringify(po))
  //throw new Error("err in first fnk");//This is for testing the 
  //error handling on the client side

  return ["name1","name2"];
}

function serverFncCall2(po) {
  Logger.log('po 2: ' + JSON.stringify(po))
  return [["one","two"]];
}
```

### Code

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("H_Index");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!  This also solved my problem with lagged results from server for my dropdown values.  Here is my code:

```
function createDropdowns() {
    
    loaddropdown("Dropdowns!A2:A","ctype");
    loaddropdown("Dropdowns!B2:B","state");
    loaddropdown("Dropdowns!C2:C","city");
    loaddropdown("Dropdowns!D2:D","remedies");
    loaddropdown("Dropdowns!E2:E","keywords");

    }
    async function loaddropdown(range,eid) {
    
    const e = await new Promise(r => {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(r).getDropdownList(range);
    }); 
    filldropdown(e,eid);
}

//POPULATE HTML DROPDOWN

function filldropdown(values, elemid) { 
    
    var list = document.getElementById(elemid);   
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = values[i];
    option.text = values[i];
    list.appendChild(option);
    
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks to who? you should mention clearly ;)